# Migrating from a 2TB MacBook Pro to a 500GB MacBook Air

Tags: hard-drive, mac, ssd, macbook

We don't want to lose any of the files.

My plan is:

1. Buy an external 2TB SSD.
2. Copy ~1.6TB of files from the old Mac onto the SSD.
3. Use migration assistant to transfer the old Mac onto the new one, excluding the files copied in step 2.
4. Connect the 2TB SSD to the new Mac.
5. Configure Time Machine to backup the new Mac and the 2TB SSD onto a 4TB external hard drive

Does this seem reasonable?

Comment: What models of MacBook Pro and MacBook Air are these? What versions of macOS are you running? And I am assuming you mean TB instead of GB in your question; I edited it to reflect TB but just a “heads up” just in case.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 Not sure about the model of either, but both should be running latest OS. Thanks for editing!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Overall, assuming your backup is 1.6 TB, your plan is reasonable.

I suggest, perhaps, a 2 TB or even a 4 TB backup drive so as to be able to backup everything. Extra space is often useful at a later time. That is how I work.

For number 3, yes.

For number 5, also yes.

It should all work.  Do indeed work very carefully.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming there is 1.6TB (not GB) worth of user files (not application files or library data), you can do that.

1. Copy User Data to new SSD (Files and Folders)
2. Migrate the system either from a backup or directly connecting to the Mac. You will get the option to select users, apps and settings usually. You have to deselect user files and folders during the migration.
3. Use the new SSD along side the new migrated system on the MacBook Air.

It is always best practice to create a full Time Machine backup including your files and folders to a hard drive prior to doing the above in case anything goes wrong.